# Is it good practise to use async in nodejs ? How to use helper function in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am new to nodejs and I want to create helper function for finding user from collection. I want to excute that helper function before adding any new document into the database. Parallaly I want to use that helper function on multiple times in other places.

When I simply create one function and store result of that function, the control is passes from that place and doesn't wait for output as Nodejs basic Async functionality.

How can I customise my code to use helper function and wait for the result and then perform required operation

How to use nested callback ?
Nested callback isn't waiting for callback data and control goes to next line

Here is my code :

```
login: function (req, res) {

    var user = helpers.checkIfDataExists(req.body.mobileNumber, function (user) {
    if (user) {
       console.log('user exists');
       var email = helpers.checkIfDataExists(req.body.email, function (email) {
          if (email) {
             console.log('email exists');
          } else {
             console.log('email not exists');
          }
      });
    } else {
       console.log('user not exists')
    }
   });
}
```

I want that control waits till function is executed and then condition will get executed.
Here control goes by default in else part everytime.

Here is code of helper function :

```
checkIfDataExists: function (value, callback) {
    User.find({mobileNumber: value})
                    .exec(function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error occured');
                            callback(false);
                        } else {
                            console.log('result found');
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callbacks. Pass a callback function to your helper function in which the results will be returned and then in your helper function write a call to that function when your computations are over.

```
checkIfDataExists: function (value, callback) {
    User.find({mobileNumber: value})
                    .exec(function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error occured');
                            callback(false);
                        } else if (!result) {
                            console.log('Not Found');
                            callback(false);
                        } else {
                            console.log('result found');
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
},
```

then use something like this in your main function.

```
signUp: function (req, res) {

    var user = helpers.checkIfDataExists(req.body.mobileNumber, function(user){

// do something with results here
log(user);
    if (!user) {
        // add new user
    } else {
        res.send("User exists");
    }
});
}
```

here is a link to [article](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) about callbacks

Comment: How could my code wait if I have nested callbacks ?
it isn't waiting for that

Comment: you can use nested callbacks also but for that you have to structure your code pretty well. It requires good practice.

Comment: the above code works anyway for your case with the code you have posted

Comment: I have edited code as per my need and now I am stucked again

Can you help me out ?

Comment: Don't do these kinds of things always be specific. If you get into some other problem then ask a new question don't edit the existing ones. It becomes misleading for the future readers. Because even if i answer with your edited question and then you will say i got into another problem and so on. I will be happy to help you on another question

Comment: Okay I will keep that in mind

Can you help me out for this question for now please ?

Comment: There is no harm in asking another question. Please try to  understand that here wefollow some rules. close this and ask another one.

Comment: I've asked new question. Please help if you know answer